# Getting a color value from a coord

Tags: python, pygame, color, pixel

My goal is to get a RGB value of a pixel based of off a X,Y coordinate.

I have been working on AIs for a small project attempting to make a bot that can pass through a maze. I want to get the pixel color in front of the bot to test if it is a wall or not. I have no example code because i don't know exactly where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
pygame.Surface.get_at(x,y)
```

to get a pixel RGBA value.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at

Comment: Will it return as a string or rgb value?

Comment: "Return a copy of the RGBA _Color value_ at the given pixel."

Comment: This (mostly correct) code should help you understand the usage of get_at:                                                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789732/cant-get-pygame-surface-get-at-to-work-properly

Answer (score 0):

```
mouse_x,mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
color = some_surface_object.get_at((mouse_x,mouse_y))
```

will return array [0=>R, 1=>G, 2=>B] in demical values [122,25,224]